# in booksleeve how do I iterate through all the keys in given db

Tags: booksleeve

I´m using booksleeve (and it is awesome) to access redis from C#. The only thing I lack is api documentation (or perhaps I haven´t found it?). I need to flush redis db to sql server, so I need to iterate through all the keys in redis db. How is this best done?

**Edit**
Ok, I've managed to do this by:

```
var conn = MyTable.RedisConnection;
var keys = conn.Keys.Find(MyTable.redis_db_index, "*").Result;
```

Comment: Not at a PC right now, but should be .Keys.List(pattern) or something like that

Comment: For info, a new key iteration API is currently in the pipeline for redis, and will be available soon.

Comment: Where can I get more info on this? I need something similar. Does new version of Booksleeve has this or new version or Redis has?

Answer (score 1):

I would use publisher/subscriber technique. It seems that Find in Booksleeve is Keys pattern command in Redis. And they do not recommend using Keys pattern in production. See http://redis.io/commands/keys .